# zuul not routing to running micro-service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

is there any possible reason why is zuul not routing towards my running micro-service after refresh (it displays the swagger page of my microservice the first time but not after refresh) ? 
the weird thing is except this message displayed in the screen

> Failed to load API definition.
>   undefined http://localhost:8080/api/auth/v2/api-docs?group=v1.0.0

no exceptions no errors ! 
and the micro-service is up and running and when i visit the url without zuul it displays the swagger page !

Comment: Have you checked the routes endpoint? `http://your-zuul-address/routes` That should tell you what routes it has registered. That error seems to be Swagger, is it possible that your swagger ui can't load the API definition when you go through zuul? Have you tried any endpoint? (If you're using Spring-cloud `/env` or `/info` should work)

Comment: it loads perfectly for the first time .. so the routes are fine, i refresh the page and hop zuul is not detecting my microservice as if it is down or its route is not configured :/ :/